# Внутренние переменные shell

Tags: linux, shell

В shell не силён, подскажите как можно выполнить при помощи скрипта такое действие:

> Сохранить в виде ascii- файла F1.var значение внутренних переменных
>   shell и номера процессов в системе.

Comment: учитывая ваш [следующий вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/584185/178576), вы явно сейчас проходите какое-то тестирование. для вас же самого полезнее будет выполнить тестовые задания **самостоятельно**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сохраняем переменные окружения:

```
printenv > F1.var
```

Сохраняем процессы в тот же файл

```
ps -aux >> F1.var
```

Сомневаюсь, что для этого нужен скрипт

---

Строго говоря, команда `printenv` выдает список переменных окружения, а не внутренних переменных оболочки, но я не очень понимаю, какую пользу в данном контексте можно получить от переменных типа `$REPLY`, `$1`, `$2`, `$#` и многих других.

Comment: `ps -axo pid`, если строго следовать условиям задачи :-)

Comment: @PinkTux если буквально, то да. А  так, кто знает, что именно там надо.

Comment: ответ на первый вопрос, конечно, неправильный, но, учитывая, что, судя по формулировке вопроса, это явно какой-то тест, пусть так и будет.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а есть команда, выдающая список установленных в данный момент *internal* переменных оболочки?

Comment: Фактически нужно просто сделать diff между выводом "чистого" окружения и printenv.  Так как printenv выводит то же окружение,  но которое формируется после загрузки шелла,  то есть с добавлением его внутренних переменных.

Comment: @andy.37, если пытаться ответить на первый вопрос формально точно, то придётся сооружать довольно громоздкую программу. но я подозреваю, что преподаватель, придумывавший вопрос, имел в виду вывод одной внутренней команды posix-совместимой оболочки. // и, кстати, printenv — это программа. а не команда.